# SonarQube StartSonar.bat is not working

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.1

What's the problem with this? It stopped again and again. What should I do?

```
jvm 1    | 2017.03.31 10:42:12 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is up
jvm 1    | 2017.03.31 10:42:14 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopp
ing
jvm 1    | 2017.03.31 10:42:14 ERROR app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[web] failed
to start
jvm 1    | 2017.03.31 10:42:14 INFO  app[][o.s.p.m.Monitor] Process[es] is stopped
```

Comment: Can you post other log files (es.log and web.log) ?

Comment: @steve A have similar problem. In my case issue was related to connection to database. Please make sure that your DB server is running up.